# how "streamus" chrome extension is streaming only audio of youtube video?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, youtube

I am creating all in one music app using multiple APIs. I want to stream only audio of youtube song. As i searched a lot but could not find actual solution. many of them says it will be against Youtube TOS. If it is so than how "StreamUs" chrome extension is working. I am not creating something this but i want to stream a song audio only as it is in above extension.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check out the source code yourself :) 
https://github.com/MeoMix/StreamusChromeExtension/tree/master/src

Comment: @ioseph Thanks for your reply but I already checked source code. They are also using JS API of youtube but as in documentation of YOUTUBE there is noting like what streamUs is using for their live streaming.

Answer (score 5):

author of Streamus here. Just dropping in to give a definitive answer.

Chrome extensions can utilize both an invisible, permanent background page as well as a visible, temporary foreground page. When the foreground page loses focus - it is destroyed and all content is unloaded from memory.

Streamus hosts the YouTube video player on the background page which gives the illusion that the video is not loaded. It pipes all commands from the foreground UI to the background page.

However, it's worth noting that this is a violation of YouTube's Terms of Service. I've been working with YouTube to figure out a good solution to the problem and am almost there with a clever way to present video in the foreground without losing the audio. :)

Comment: Hey Sean, I will look forward for your solution. And thanks for above info

Answer (score 1):

`Unfortunately it does pull the video as well for bandwidth, but good question.`

as quoted by the author in 
https://www.reddit.com/r/streamus/comments/1w64wj/question/ .